# Appium [Android] - Couldn't launch app on virtual device

Tags: automated-tests, android-virtual-device, appium

I installed Appium and all necessary stuff for running of application via Android AVD

Then I started a virtual device and launched the Appium (sure path to application was set in Settings before launching) http://take.ms/wRG8w

I don't know whether the application should be open immediately after launching or not. Thats why I ran Inspector. Seems the device was connected and Inspector was launched BUT the only thing I saw was Android logo.. launched application wasn't presented and as a result I wasn't able to record anything, here is screenshot http://take.ms/caglt

Maybe it was caused because of super slow virtual device.. please help

Answer (score 0):

It's because the andriod emulator is very slow. Best is to use android device itself. I had same issues. There options to accelerate the simulator, but they haven't worked for me

If you have any andriod tab or phone, its quite easy to get started. You need to get adb  installed ( is been done from the logs I see)and the driver of the phone device.

Then do adb devices to see if the device is listed. After that you can easily start interacting with device.